# VanillaJS library into directive

Tags: angular, reactjs, single-page-application

How to expose a js(vanillaJS) api to other applications(Angular, react, VueJS) as a custom directive/ component. So that, it can be used in other applications.

To give an example, if my library is inserting a DOM element and host some async content into it. I need to call in the source page as below.

```
new dynContent({domParentId,})
```

But I want to use as a HTML directive as below.

```
<dynContent domParentId="someId" />
```

Comment: Could you be more specific of if you could mention some example that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Component is a completely different thing. If the `js` file that you are trying to expose is going to do some operation (like a library) then it could be easily put in a `directive`.